# What do the light signals on the cars mean?

Tags: anki-overdrive

The Anki Supercars all have different lights that signal various things. Sadly, the meaning of the colors are never explained anywhere in the game or in the documentation.

So far I gathered these meanings:

- lights on the front: active when weapons are fired.
- lights at the back: red when being hit

[image]

- light on the top:

  - static red/blue: signaling which driver they belong to
    [image]
  - static green: fully charged, not in a game
  - pulsating green: charging
  - white: hit by tractor beam etc.

I observed a couple of times that the top light of a car, while in a game, was alternating between green and the player color, and I can't figure out what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the start, when the cars are chosen, the color indicates the player color.

Right before the start the light flashes according to the countdown, three times yellow, then green when the race starts.

During the race:

The light on the top changing color is an indicator of energy (health/ammo, not power):

- Green means full
- yellow means around half full
- and red means low
- flashing red means disabled

When the vehicle receives damage the light flashes according to the damage type.

A blue light indicates that the vehicle is invulnerable. This occurs at the race start and when a vehicle has recovered from being disabled.

More details can be found in the [Anki Knowledge Base](https://support.anki.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000832128-Anki-OVERDRIVE-What-s-new-with-the-top-LED-).

Comment: Between the time I asked this question and it was answered an updated was released that changed the behavior of the lights. This answer doesn't match my original question, but it describes the current state, hence I'll mark it as accepted. I also took the liberty of extending it with information from the official knowledge base.